# Number of integer partitions of $n$ with exactly $k$ parts from the set $S = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_m\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Specifically, I want to find the number of integer partitions of 1000 into exactly 100 parts of sizes {5, 20, 100} ignoring different orderings. I am trying to find the generating function. I have seen other answers using $[x^n]$ which I think is referring to the q-analog but I am not sure. I am a little fuzzy on that topic so if someone could explain it, I would greatly appreciate it.

I would also like to know how to do this in general.

Comment: In relation to generating functions, $[x^n]$ means the coefficient of $x^n$ if the GF. I.e. if for example $f(x) = 2 + 3x^2 +5x^3$, then $[x^3]f(x) = 5$.

Comment: Could you also please link to one of the earlier answers you refer to and explain what you understand / don't understand?